# Unity/ How to reference the child pivot to the parent pivot?

Tags: unity-game-engine, pivot, layer

I have an item that the player can pick up, and when that happens I set the `GameObject` as a child of the player but the pivot does not change. When the player is ahead of another item, if the pivot point of the other item is "under" the child one, then the sorting order will be: Player, other item, pickUp object. [Here, the item that is picked up is the pot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n97ck.png)

I tried to change the sprite sorting order (in the `SpriteRenderer` component) of both the `GameObject`s to pivot, but that did not work.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? It is not very clear to me what you are trying to achieve and what exactly your question is about

Comment: I would like when i make a gameobject as a child that the sprite renderer of both the child and the parent have the same layer ( so they appear both on or under other stuff) in the image that i sent before you can see that this doesn't happen and that you have in this order: the player, the rock and the pot (which is a child of the player so it should be shown before the rock). Hope this was more clear, thank you.

Comment: the moment you pickup the item set it to `item.sortingOrder = player.sortingOrder;` (or use sortingLayerID according to your needs) and on drop/release reset it to whatever it had previously?